# pass two variable inside ajax data call in jquery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

I get two variable in my jquery function and how i pass it in my data inside ajax call and get it in laravel controller

This is my function

```
$('#updateProduct').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);
    var redirect_url = $(this).find("[name='redirect_url']").val();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var method = $(this).attr('method');
    var videos = document.getElementById('videoToUpload').files[0];
      var myData ={
      'name': $(this).find("[name='name']").val(),
      'description': $(this).find("[name='description']").val(),
      'brand': $(this).find("[name='brand']").val(),
      'category': $(this).find("[name='category']").val(),
      'condition': $(this).find("[name='condition']").val(),
      'shipper': $(this).find("[name='shipper']").val(),
      'shipping_from': $(this).find("[name='shipping_from']").val(),
      'shipping_paid_by': $(this).find("[name='shipping_paid_by']").val(),
      'shipping_within' :$(this).find("[name='shipping_within']").val(),
      'shipping_weight': $(this).find("[name='shipping_weight']").val(),
      'shipping_fee': $(this).find("[name='shipping_fee']").val(),
      'seller_get' : $(this).find("[name='seller_get']").val(),
      'price_per_unit': $(this).find("[name='price_per_unit']").val(),
      'selling_fee' : $(this).find("[name='selling_fee']").val(),
      'is_active':$(this).find("[name='is_active']:checked").val(),
      //'videos' :$("#videoToUpload").files[0],
     //'videos' : document.getElementById('videoToUpload').files[0],
    }
    console.log(data);
   $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        dataType: 'JSON',
       data: {'myData':myData
               'videos':new FormData("videos", document.getElementById('videoToUpload').files[0])
               },
        success: function(data){
          alert("Products updated successfullly");
          console.log(data);
           //window.location.href = redirect_url;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
          console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        }
      });
```

Here i am having two variable one `videos` and other `myData` now my question is how to pass these two variable in data and request this variable in laravel controller

Comment: put a comma after `'myData':myData`

Comment: you can put videos under myData it self.

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik when i give like this it shows me an error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Answer (score 0):

You have done everything well, but forget to write comma

```
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: url,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {'myData': myData, 'videos': new FormData("videos", document.getElementById('videoToUpload').files[0]) },
    success: function(data){
      // .........
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // .........
    }
  });
```

By the way, don't spend time to define each input to variable, use [jquery serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)  and [PHP unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php), or you can use this code below to create [Serialize Object](https://codepen.io/seriema/pen/nupEJ)

```
    $.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

Comment: @lennon i gave comma and tried but after submitting the form it show me an  error that illegal invocation

Comment: @Karthiga can you update the question and write html <form>?